# Powershell Invoke-SSHCommand: Exception calling “EndExecute” with “1” argument(s)

Tags: powershell, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a Netscaler SDX server via the Posh-SSH module in powershell, to search for a specific file and then download it. If i connect to the server with putty it works and I can then enter "shell" to open a normal bash console.
When i try to connect with powershell i use following commands.

```
$hostname = [ip]
$user = [username]
$password = [password]

$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 
$user, $secureStringPwd

$ssh = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $HostName -Credential $creds
```

This creates a ssh session which still seams to work. Next I use Invoke-SSHCommand.

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId ssh.SessionId -Command "shell"
```

It loads for a while and then throws out this exception:

```
Exception calling "EndExecute" with "1" argument(s):  "Command 
'shell' has timed out."
At C:\Users\giapsh\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-ssh\Posh-
SSH.psm1:266 char:25
+                         $Output = $_.cmd.EndExecute($_.Async)
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SshOperationTimeoutException
```

I googled for it, I only found someone with the same problem but no answer (used that to translate from german to english). I also tried other things like "ls" for commands but the same error returned. Does someone have an Idea what I am doing wrong?

I'm using Windows 10 and Powershell 5.1

Regards

Patrick

Comment: I believe the issue here is that `Posh SSH` runs a command and then returns the output. When you are executing `shell`, it runs the command and waits for the output, but since the command is an interactive shell then it times out waiting for something to return. Posh SSH is not like PuTTy but like Plink

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. Try SSHStream commands:

```
PS C:\> $SSHStream = New-SSHShellStream -Index 0
PS C:\> $SSHStream.WriteLine("uname -a")
PS C:\> $SSHStream.read()
Last login: Sat Mar 14 20:02:16 2015 from infidel01.darkoperator.com
[admin@localhost ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 30 12:09:22 
UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[admin@localhost ~]$
```